# Multiplication of all elements in a group

Tags: group-theory

$G$ is a finite abelian group that for every $g \in G$ we have $g^2= e$ and $|G|\geq3$. prove that multiplication of all elements in $G$ is $e$.

Comment: The easy way to see this is true is the fact that every element has a unique inverse. the group is abelian, so you can always reorganize your multiplication so that they cancel.

Comment: Definitely not. All elements are inverse to themselves, so they dont cancel. What you are talking about is the following: The product of all elements in a finite abelian group is the product of all elements of order $2$.

Answer (score 2):

"Another" way of seeing this, is the following:

It is well known that $G$ is a $\mathbb F_2$ vector-space in this case, so we are asked to show $\sum_{x \in \mathbb F_2^n} x = 0$ if $n \geq 2$ (now $n$ is directly related to the group order, thats why i have $n \geq 2$ here...). This is an easy one:

$\sum_{x \in \mathbb F_2^n} x = \sum_{y \in \mathbb F_2^{n-1}} ((y,0)+(y,1)) = \sum_{y \in \mathbb F_2^{n-1}} (0,1)=(0,2^{n-1})=0$ since $2^{n-1}$ is even.

It is literally the same proof as above, but it uses somehow another language and might be easier to understand for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

$G$ has to be a finite group. Consider $e \neq x \in G$. By Lagrange we obtain a disjoint cover

$G = \bigcup_{i=1}^{2^n} x_i\langle x \rangle = \bigcup_{i=1}^{2^n} \{x_i,x_ix \}$ for some $x_i$.

By assumption we have $n \geq 1$, so $2^n$ is even.

This shows that the product of all elements is $x^{2^n}=e$

Comment: the sets in cover are not disjoint. maybe we have $x_i = x_j x$ for some $i,j$.

Comment: You should have another look at Lagrange's Theorem. It precisley states, that there is such a disjoint cover with cosets of a given subgroup.

Comment: the cover will be disjoint if you get from every clase just one element but when you are getting all elements in $G$ you will cover every element for two times. but you can edit your solution and it and write $G = \bigcup_{i=1}^{2^{n-1}} x_i\langle x \rangle$. in this case you will user from condition $n\geq 3$ and it is important that the theorem is not true for $n=2$.

Comment: Have i ever stated, that $n$ is somehow related to the group order? I have just chosen $2^n$ to be the number of cosets of the subgroup $\langle x \rangle$. You should think more carefully, before you doubt someones answer to your question.